# Is it possible to align windows to other windows instead of fixed half screen?

Tags: unity, compiz, window-manager

Currently I can only make windows half or quarter of the screen, but if I resize a windows, like 1/3 width of the screen, then I want to move another window to the remaining 2/3 of the screen, I simply can't, because I can only drag the window to half a screen.

I tried solving this with CompizConfig but I didn't found any related stuff there.

Comment: Do look at proper tiling window managers like i3wm or ratpoison (though they're considered to be a bit difficult to get used to for beginners).

Answer (score 0):

**No**, currently you cannot do so with compiz, which is required by Unity. Because the **Grid** plugin from compiz only allow you half-split the window.

But, there are plans to make the grid sizes configurable in future. From the [Compiz Wiki page for Grid plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid), under ideas section, these are mentioned

> 1. Make the grid size reconfigurable instead of the fixed 33%,50%,66% sizes (ie. Maybe an even better option is to retain the 2x3 grid, but allow the user to specify how big the grid blocks are.)
> 2. Perhaps assign a layout per workspace or hotkey to switch between grid sizes